# combine two ParametricPlot3D plots

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following parametric equations

```
x0[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := a* Cos[u]*Sin[v]
y0[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := b* Sin[u]*Sin[v]
z0[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := c*Cos[v]

x1[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := 0
y1[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := b* Sin[u]*Sin[v]
z1[u_, v_, a_, b_, c_] := c*Cos[v]
```

Now I take the plots

```
g1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x0[u, v, 10, 3, 2], y0[u, v, 10, 3, 2], 
    z0[u, v, 10, 3, 2]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, \[Pi]}, 
   Mesh -> None];

g2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x1[u, v, 10, 3, 2], y1[u, v, 10, 3, 2], 
   z1[u, v, 10, 3, 2]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, \[Pi]}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> LightBlue]
```

How can I combine them in order the second plot to be visible (like an Epilog object for g1)?

I want something like the following output

```
Show[g2, g1]
```

but the whole ellipsoid should be plot.
Thank you.

Comment: add the option `PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]` to `g1` and use `Show[g1,g2]`?

Comment: @kguler Sorry, didn't see your comment before posting. Moved my answer to CW

Comment: @kguler, thank for the answer

Comment: @belisarius, happens to me all the time. Don't think it is necessary to make your answer CW - can you undo it?

Comment: @kguler I don't care either. Let's keep it CW.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x0[u, v, 10, 3, 2], y0[u, v, 10, 3, 2], 
   z0[u, v, 10, 3, 2]}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, π}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]]

g2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x1[u, v, 10, 3, 2], y1[u, v, 10, 3, 2], 
   z1[u, v, 10, 3, 2]}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, π}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> LightBlue]

Show[g1, g2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Moved to CW after seeing @kguler's comment ...

Comment: Belisarius, thank for the answer. By the way, I can reproduce this coloring for g1. Instead what I get is an orange-like coloring. How to modify it?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Scale[#, {3, 1, 1}], Opacity[1], 
    Scale[#, {.001, 1, 1}]} &@Sphere[]]
```

[image: spheres]

This (self-contained) short form is possible here because ellipsoids are just scaled spheres.

By the way, the `Scale` with `0.001` in the `x` direction is also a good way to render disks in 3D.

Comment: Thank you very much. No need for parametric equations:-)!